# Android Volley large data load

Tags: php, android, android-volley, android-recyclerview

I have a problem that need some advice from a senior android programmer. 
I have a `android application` that will load data on the `recyclerview`, in this `recyclerview` we have searching field and a distance column.

The question is if I load data set with `pagination` i cannot sort `recyclerview` by `distance` and the `search function` become useless because i cannot search data that not have been load. 
`Distance` is calculating once i have `lat` and `long` from the data that have been load.

This is Search method:

```html
@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        final List<Warkop> filteredWarkopList = filter(warkopList, newText);

        warkopAdapter.setFilter(filteredWarkopList);

        return true;
    }

    private List<Warkop> filter(List<Warkop> warkopList, String newText) {

        newText = newText.toLowerCase();
        final List<Warkop> filteredWarkopList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Warkop model : warkopList){

                final String text = model.getNamaWarkop().toLowerCase();

                if (text.contains(newText)) {
                    filteredWarkopList.add(model);
                }

            }

        return filteredWarkopList;
    }

//Adapter data filter

 public void setFilter(List<Warkop> filterWarkopList){

    mWarkop = new ArrayList<>();
    mWarkop.addAll(filterWarkopList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

thank you

Comment: i see no reason for a `php` tag on this post here

Comment: who's know there is a trick on JRON return from PHP page.